# Не отображаются картинки на pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Делаю проект на pyqt5, вот как он выглядит
[image: qtdesigner]
но при запуске пайтон кода или при предпросмотре в qtdesigner, он не загружает большинство картинок (2 изображение). Файл плашки весит 200кб, что сравнительно немного, так что я не могу определить корень проблемы

[image: пайтон файл]

Comment: хорошо выглядит, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick https://yadi.sk/d/9ngsyXdscd5R1A?w=1 ссылка на код и картинку плашки

Comment: я не могу прочитать вашу ссылку, 
или составьте [mcve], или разместите на `github`